# Why is sqlite a MongoDB dependency when installing MongoDB with Homebrew

Tags: mongodb, macos, sqlite, homebrew

While installing MongoDB on macOS using Homebrew, one of the lines I noticed is:

`==> Installing mongodb dependency: sqlite`

Out of curiosity, what is the connection there? Why is sqlite a dependency of mongodb?

Comment: `sqlite` shouldn't be an explicit dependency for MongoDB and isn't mentioned in the Homebrew formula: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mongodb.rb. What is your `brew` command line?

Comment: Using macOS Terminal, `Homebrew 1.6.1`.

Comment: Is your command line anything more exotic than `brew install mongodb`? Have you configured your `brew` to prefer source builds? The default install should be a binary package (aka "bottle") with output headings like  "==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mongodb-3.6.4.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz" and "==> Pouring mongodb-3.6.4.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz". Building from source or using non-default config options may pull in other build dependencies. It would help if you could update your question with the command line & options used as well as the full `brew` output.

Comment: I have not done any additional configuration of brew to prefer source builds or anything like that. Forgive my ignorance, but what would be the best way to get the most useful information for both the command line and for brew? Happy to update my question with all relevant options.

Comment: Since this outcome isn't reproducible with a default bottled install (which wouldn't have any extra dependencies), I assume your install must be building from source. The exact command line you're using (`brew install mongodb`?) and output of that could be useful since you've currently only quoted a single line. What version of MongoDB gets installed? What is the output of `db.serverBuildInfo().gitVersion` in the `mongo` shell? You could also check if `HOMEBREW_BUILD_FROM_SOURCE` is set in your environment: `env  | grep HOMEBREW`.

Comment: Exact command line: `brew install mongodb`, but I don't have the exact results from the previous installation, results of `db.serverBuildInfo().gitVersion: d0181a711f7e7f39e60b5aeb1dc7097bf6ae5856` and no evironment variable set for `HOMEBREW_BUILD_FROM_SOURCE`.

Comment: I did `brew install mongodb` and I saw that same line during installation `==> Installing mongodb dependency: sqlite`. That is really weird :')

Comment: Can confirm this occurs for me as well when executing `brew install mongodb`.

Comment: Can also confirm.

Comment: Same here these two are not related at all

Answer (score 1):

It appears that certain flavors of MongoDB now use SQLite as a backend: https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/mobile/mobile-overview/